# Explain line of code specifically where it says t

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to know what the `t`in the line of code below stands for. Is the "t" user defined or is it dependent on the database?

```
Survey_Time_Period[] getTimePeriods = 
     (from t in dc.Survey_Time_Periods 
        where t.display == true orderby t.sort descending select t)
     .ToArray();
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JSON or Javascript - or even ASP.NET - as far as I can see. You should read up on LINQ, in particular query expressions in C#.

Comment: t is a range variable representing the "current" record in `dc.Survey_Time_Periods` in the context of the query.

Comment: @BenRobinson  I see. Is this something that was defined by the user or is it defined in the database?

Comment: @JonSkeet as I stated previously I am a noob so forgive me if the tags are wrong but I wanted to include all languages used to build the app.

Comment: @BenRobinson: Well, it's a range variable. I'm not sure I'd describe it as a local variable... range variables are a bit unusual.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have updated my comment, I wasn't quite sure of the correct term.

Comment: @BenRobinson thanks Ben. I Appreciate you baring with me as I try to explain. So I should look up LINQ and range variables, correct?

Comment: @user5333955 Read up on Linq yes.

Comment: @user5333955 In the future, only tag the question with things that are relevant to your current issue. You may be dealing with an ASP.NET app that uses JSON and JavaScript, but your question is purely about C# and one of its language features (LINQ) and thus isn't specific to ASP.NET, and isn't related at all to JavaScript or JSON. Don't sweat it, just something to keep in mind for the future. A good way to decide what's relevant is to think of your question in it's simplest terms. Reading over [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may get you in the right mindset.

Comment: @mason understood. Again thanks for all your help. I am new to c# still trying to figure this out. But you guys have been extremely helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This syntax is a [LINQ query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx). You can see a lot of great LINQ examples [here](http://linq101.nilzorblog.com/linq101-lambda.php).

`t` is a range variable representing an enumerated instance of whatever type is enumerated from `dc.Survey_Time_Periods`, in this case a single `Survey_Time_Period` object. `t` is only valid within the context of the LINQ query. Later on in the LINQ query, it's filtering on the `Survey_Time_Period.display` property and then ordering by the `Survey_Time_Period.sort` property, then returning the resulting instances of `Survey_Time_Period`.

There are two LINQ syntaxes, and it may be helpful for you to see the equivalent statement in the other LINQ syntax. This alternate syntax utilizes [lambda expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

```
Survey_Time_Period[] getTimePeriods = dc.Survey_Time_Periods
    .Where(t => t.display == true)
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.sort)
    .ToArray();
```

Note that your variable names aren't in keeping with the C# standards. Don't use underscores in variable names, and don't prefix a variable with a verb. Also, comparing a boolean to true isn't necessary, because the boolean already represents true or false. If you adjust your type names and variable names, it becomes a little cleaner:

```
var timePeriods = dc.SurveyTimePeriods
    .Where(stp => stp.Display)
    .OrderByDescending(stp => stp.Sort)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Mason's you have shed light on this situation for me. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's rewrite *Linq* in a different format:

```
Survey_Time_Period[] getTimePeriods = dc.Survey_Time_Periods // Source
  .Where(item => item.display)           // Filter
  .OrderByDescending(item => item.sort)  // Sorting
  .ToArray();                            // Materialization (representation)
```

that means:

1. Select all items from `dc.Survey_Time_Periods`
2. Such that `item.display == true` (filter)
3. Order the filtered items by `item.sort` in *descending order*
4. Represent the filtered and ordered items as *array*

Comment: Thank you so much for providing a different way of looking at this. Would this style syntax be accepted using the LINQs?

Comment: @user5333955: yes this kind of syntax is a typical one for Linq queries.